# Issues with Barchart in mpandroidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using mpandroidchart in my android app. I am facing some issues.

[image]

As you can see, there is a part of graph shown below lower datum of bars(area where 'Description' is displayed).This issue is there only when one of the Y value is 0 as in this case. How to get rid of it?Also, how to get rid of 'Description'?

Another issue is as:

[image]

Here you can see several issues. First, a large part of the view is empty below the X labels(When X labels are big I need to rotate it so that all labels are dsplayed,otherwise graph  only displays alternate labels on X axis). I want graph to occupy as much space as possible. But it occupies only a part of it.
Second issue here is the height of graphs. They are quite disproportionate. I want uniform heights of bar proportional to their values(like in first picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By removing the description, the extra area will go off.
Try to remove the description by setting `barChart.setDescription("");`.

If not worked, try

`YAxis yAxisLeft = barChart.getAxisLeft();
 yAxisLeft.setAxisMinValue(0f);`

`YAxis yAxisRight = barChart.getAxisRight();
 yAxisRight.setAxisMinValue(0f);`

For second one, you need to set the chart minimum height to fill the area.
`android:layout_height="match_parent"` won't work for MPAndroidChart.

Set `barChart.setMinimumHeight(height);`

For graph uniform height try this:

`YAxis yAxisLeft = barChart.getAxisLeft();
 yAxisLeft.setAxisMinValue(0f);`

`YAxis yAxisRight = barChart.getAxisRight();
 yAxisRight.setAxisMinValue(0f);`

By setting the axis minimum value to zero, the chart will draw from zero and you will get the uniform height.

Comment: Thanks a ton Madhu...would implement your recommendations.